# Using ElasticSearch with Hadoop Map Reduce

Tags: text, hadoop, lucene, elasticsearch, bigdata

I have a 'big data' text search problem, and I had looked for general advice on a Stackexchange site here - https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/203855/text-search-big-data-problem

There is a specific question in mind here for this SO post, namely around integration of ElasticSearch with Hadoop (but I thought I'd provide some background).

**Problem overview**

Basically I have a large amount of text, split into distinct 'rows', each row represents an item.  I have another, smaller list, which contains search terms that are in this text.  I want to cross-reference the two and do an inverse index look up, and return the indexes that I find.

**Note: I know that 20GB isn't massive data, but a secondary objective of this exercise is to engage with Big Data techs to lay a foundation for us to use with our true big data (> TB) projects!**

**Approach**

I've continued to investigate the Lucene search route, but as far as I can see this would lead to the following approach:

- Use MapReduce to remove stop words and format the text etc
- Generate Lucene Index (possibly using MapReduce - this is an optimization)
- Develop a C# app to interface with Lucene (or SolR) and do the search.

But to me this would still be serial, i.e. I'd be depending on the scalability of the search servers to be really quick, but I'd still have to start at the top of my list and work my way through it, one after another.

I *could* split the original list into chunks, and run my C# app on a different server, that would be an approach.

**The specific question**

But I was wondering if I could use Hadoop Map Reduce to engage directly with ElasticSearch (my preferred route to Lucene) ?  I have searched (!) but can't find anything, except using Wonderdog with Pig.  Fine - but I can't see an example with a Pig UDF and ElasticSearch.

Any pointers appreciated, code examples very welcome!

Duncan

Comment: Is it one time deal or you will have more data coming in the future, or maybe data will be more or less static but new categories will show up and you will need to detect them against old data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to make this work.

One possible way would be to have each hadoop node run an embedded routing only elastic search node. That should make querying a bit more efficient since the node will figure out which nodes need to be contacted for each query and utilize the efficient internal protocol to do so. You can scale horizontally by adding more es data nodes.

The only downside is that your hadoop nodes will not be close to the data which will be on different nodes; so you have a bit of latency for going over the network. But even so, you should be able to run large amounts of what look like it should be pretty cheap queries this way. Since it is only 20GB, your es nodes should rarely have to go to disk and can do everything in memory, utilize filter caches, etc.

I'm actually doing some disambiguation using non hadoop code against elastic search in a 1 node cluster and I'm managing between 2000-2500 simple queries per second without really stressing elastic search too much. Took me about 45 minutes to process 7 million documents. Add nodes to scale. Your milage may vary of course.

With many hadoop nodes you can sort of counter the latency effect by having a lot of concurrent requests and a large ES cluster should easily keep up with the collective load. Simply increase the number of replicas to decrease load per node.

You could probably utilize the bulk index api as well as part of your reduce step. Another idea is to use search_type=scan to iterate over all documents in elastic search instead of using files in hdfs. Optional, but might work well.

Answer (score 4):

There's a new official support for that called elasticsearch-hadoop

Take a look here: http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/elasticsearch-and-hadoop/

Also: https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-hadoop